# Align badge items in bootstrap list-group without custom css file

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying bootstrap 3
here is the code

```
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="list-group">
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-info">All inbox <span class="badge">1099</span></a>
        <div class="list-group-item">
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item-heading">Unread <span class="badge">100</span></a>
            <br>
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item-text">Today <span class="badge">10</span></a>
            <br>
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item-text">This week <span class="badge">23</span></a>
            <br>
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item-text">This month <span class="badge">67</span></a>
        </div>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-success">Bookmarked <span class="badge">3</span></a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-danger">Deleted <span class="badge">10</span></a>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- scripts here   -->
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

the result is [image: end result]

how do I get the numbers of links Unread, Today, This week, This month align to the right like the rest? `Unread` should be heading item and `Today`, `This week`, `This month` need to be subitems.

without using custom css file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS would be a simpler solution. But if you can't use CSS, you must change your HTML. The key is to take advantage of the existing Bootstrap CSS rule that makes the badges float to the right on All Inbox, Bookmarked, and Deleted:

```
.list-group-item > .badge {
  float: right;
}
```

This means elements with the class `badge` must be directly inside an element with the class `list-group-item`- not nested inside another element, like you have it now.

This might change your layout, though. If you want to keep your layout as-is, add the class `pull-right` to each `span` with the class `badge`. This will make the badges float to the right.

Comment: @Doc, sorry - I know Bootstrap, but I am a Git newb!